# Custom Performance Counters for values from +180.000 to -180.000

Tags: performance, counter

I am creating an application to monitor GPS performance, and would like to monitor position readings that range from  -180.000 up to +180.000 with a precision of at least 4 decimal places. Is this possible using Performance Counters? I have tried the Rawfraction and Rawbase with some success, but I get errors (large non-negative numbers like 71582785536) when the values go negative, using NextValue().

I am attracted to performance counters because of all the logging, scheduling, remote access, security, and analysis tools available, but I am afraid I am trying to get a round peg into a square hole. If this is not possible, would Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) be a more appropriate route?

Comment: Which system are you talking about?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I am developing for Windows Vista or later, .NET 3.5, using C#, but could do C++ for some low level things though. Could move from .NET 3.5 to a later version too.